# summarise() giving empty output

Tags: r

I am attempting to give each respondent to my survey an average score for a particular subscale.

example data (group of 5 participants responding to 3 questions of subscale):

```
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
n <- 5
data <- data.frame(id=1:n, 
              Q1= c(5 3,5,2,5),
              Q2= c(7,4,NA,2,5),
              Q3= c(1,2,2,NA,4)
```

I am using the following code to create a dataframe with each participant's average, however when I do the output is empty yielding a table with one cell that reads NA.

```
library(dplyr) 
detach(package::plyr)
test.question <- data %>%
group_by(id) %>%
summarise(ave.score = mean(c(Q1, Q2, Q3)))
```

My friend had advised me to detach plyr as they were advised by their colleague but the problem persists. How can I get a proper summary which lists participant id in the first column and their average score in the next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is row wise mean, either use `rowMeans` or with `rowwise`.  If both `plyr` and `dplyr` are loaded, the masking can be resolved by `::` directing the function to the specific package

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  rowwise %>%
  dplyr::summarise(id, ave.score = mean(c(Q1, Q2, Q3), na.rm = TRUE), 
          .groups = 'drop')
```

Another option is also with `c_across`

```
data %>%
  rowwise %>%
  dplyr::summarise(id, ave.score = mean(c_across(starts_with('Q')), 
            na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```